# Does a method contain a race condition if it checks (independent) A and then acts on B?

Tags: java, multithreading, race-condition

Consider the following class:

```
public class CheckThenAct
{
    private volatile boolean flag = false;
    public void setFlag(boolean flag) { this.flag = flag; }
    public boolean getFlag() { return flag; }

    private final Map<String, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    public void removeIfFlag(String x)
    {
        if (flag)
            map.remove(x);
    }
}
```

Does `removeIfFlag(String)` contain a race condition?

The only examples thus far that I have read have conditions and writes that are somehow related to each other (for example checking and writing on the same collection object) - In this case, there are no constraints between these two fields and they are not the same objects.

Comment: Well, not a *data-race* per se, the way the Java Language Spec defines one.  But you likely have an atomicity issue.  This code is "thread-safe" but probably won't work as you want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have one thread that calls `setFlag(true)`, and another thread that calls `removeIfFlag`.

If nothing but chance determines which thread will get to the flag first (i.e., if the threads are not synchronized/coordinated/interlocked/whatever-you-may-call-it) then that's a data race.

If the output of your program depends on which thread wins the race, then that's a *race condition*.

If the *correctness* of your program depends on which thread wins the race, then that's a bug.

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly the answer I was looking for.